# Filter again result in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php, and mysql database name daily_data2 were i can filter table in daterange using date timepicker(1st query), and i can also filter per dept(2nd query), this two filtering option are working in different button, but my problem is how can used the result in 1st query to filter per dept(2nd query)? Or should i combined my 2 queries in 1 condition only? can someone help me. Below is my code.

```
 <?php

 $post_at = "";
 $post_at_to_date = "";

 if(isset($_POST['post_at']) && isset($_POST['post_at_to_date']))
  {
    $post_at = $_POST['post_at'];
    $post_at_to_date = $_POST['post_at_to_date'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM daily_data2 WHERE Checkdate between '" . $post_at . "' and '" . $post_at_to_date . "'";

    $search_result = filter($query);
  }
  else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM daily_data2";
    $search_result = filter($sql);
  }
  function filter($query)
  {
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","bio_db");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
  }             

 ?>

 <?php

  if(isset($_POST['go']))
  {
    $cmbDept = $_POST['cmbDept'];
    $query ="SELECT * FROM $row array WHERE Campaign LIKE '".$cmbDept."' ";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
  }
 function filterTable($query)
 {
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","bio_db");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
  }             

 ?>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Employee Logs</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>
        .table-content{border-top:#CCCCCC 4px solid; width:50%;}
.table-content th {padding:5px 20px; background: #F0F0F0;vertical-align:top;} 
.table-content td {padding:5px 20px; border-bottom: #F0F0F0 1px solid;vertical-align:top;} 
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2 align="center">Time and Attendance Monitoring</h2>

    <center>

 <form name="frmSearch" method="POST" action="index.php">
    <p class="search_input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="From Date" id="post_at" name="post_at"  value="<?php echo $post_at; ?>" class="input-control" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="To Date" id="post_at_to_date" name="post_at_to_date" style="margin-left:10px"  value="<?php echo $post_at_to_date; ?>" class="input-control"  />             
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" >
    </p>


    <form method="POST" action="excel.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmbDept" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['cmbDept']) ? $_POST['cmbDept'] : ''; ?>"> 
        <input type="submit" name="export_excel" class="btn btn-success" value="Export to Excel">
        </form> 




    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <select id="cmbDept" name="cmbDept">
        <option value = '' selected="selected">Filter by Department</option>
            <option value = 'TKV'>TKV</option>
            <option value = 'NA'>NA</option>
            <option value = 'PURE-INC'>PURE INC</option>
            <option value = 'DUTY-FREE'>DUTY-FREE</option>
            <option value = 'HQL'>HQL</option>
            <option value = 'PRO-XPN'>PRO-XPN</option>
            <option value = 'Mate1'>Mate1</option>
            <option value = 'STUDENT-rUS'>STUDENT-rUS</option>
            <option value = 'COLLECTIONS'>COLLECTIONS</option>
            <option value = 'NTD'>NTD</option>
            <option value = 'DATA RESEARCHER'>DATA RESEARCHER</option>
            <option value = 'VA'>DATA RESEARCHER</option>

        </select>           
        <input type="submit" name="go" value="Filter"><br><br>

     </center>

     <table align="center" width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Userid</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Campaign</th>
            <th>Checkdate</th>
            <th>Hoursworked</th>
            <th>Overtime</th>
        </tr>

     <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Userid'];?></td>
            <td width="200"><?php echo $row['Name'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Campaign'];?>  </td>
            <td width="100" style="text-align:center;"><?php echo    $row['Checkdate'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Hoursworked'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Overtime'];?></td>
        </tr>

     <?php endwhile;?>

        </table>
        </form> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "datepicker.png",
        buttonText: "Date Picker",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'  
    });
        $(function() {
        $("#post_at").datepicker();
        $("#post_at_to_date").datepicker();
    });
    </script>


   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You will want to add another where clause in the same query so you only have to query your database once.

NOTE: you should use some form of prepared queries when using mysql in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you guys, i finally figured it out, i just combined my 2 queries into one, here's were i came up with my query. Hope it helps

```
 if(isset($_POST['post_at']) && isset($_POST['post_at_to_date']) && isset($_POST['cmbDept']))
    {
        $query ="SELECT * FROM daily_data2 WHERE Campaign = '".$cmbDept."' and Checkdate between '{'" . $post_at . "'}' and '{'" . $post_at_to_date . "'}'";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Join the query and keep it only one, something like:

```
  if(isset($_POST['post_at']) && isset($_POST['post_at_to_date']))
  {
    if(isset($_POST['go'])) {

      $cmbDept = $_POST['cmbDept'];
      $post_at = $_POST['post_at'];
      $post_at_to_date = $_POST['post_at_to_date'];
      $query = "SELECT * FROM daily_data2 WHERE Campaign LIKE '".$cmbDept."' " AND Checkdate between '" . $post_at . "' and '" . $post_at_to_date . "'";

    } else {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM daily_data2 WHERE Checkdate between '" . $post_at . "' and '" . $post_at_to_date . "'";
    }

  } else {

     if(isset($_POST['go'])) {
        $cmbDept = $_POST['cmbDept'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM daily_data2 WHERE Campaign LIKE '".$cmbDept."'";
     } else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM daily_data2";
     }
  }

  $search_result = filter($query);

  function filter($query)
  {
     $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","bio_db");
     $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
     return $filter_Result;
  }
```

Comment: Right, you can modify according to your need. Helper just judges based on partial code and may not have all ideas.